# Create a docker image/container from EC2 AMI

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, docker-registry

I am very new to docker and am trying to import my AWS EC2 AMI into  a docker image. The image is a m2 linux image.

I have also setup a private docker hub(artifactory) to which I intend to push the image and make it available for consumption. What are the steps for importing AMI into docker image without starting from a base image and updating.

Pointers to any explanation would work too.

Answer (score 32):

Here is how I did it.

- On source AMI locate root volume snapshot id in the description

**/dev/sda1=`snap-eb79b0b1`:15:true:gp2**

- Launch instance with public Ubuntu 14.04 AMI
- Create volume from snapshot snap-eb79b0b1 (in the same region that the instance runs).
- Attach volume to the instance as `/dev/sdf`
- mount volume to `/mnt`

`mount /dev/xvdf /mnt`

(or)

`mount /dev/xvdf1 /mnt`

- install docker

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/

- import docker image from mounted root volume

`tar -c -C /mnt/ . | docker import - appcimage-master-1454216413`

- run

`docker run -t -i 6d6614111fcb03d5ca79541b8a23955202dfda74995d968b5ffb5d45c7e68da9 /bin/bash`

Comment: Couple comments
1) mount /dev/xvdf1 /mnt
2) Docker install with script
https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-convenience-script

Comment: This answer totally worked. However, I'm unable to run a container from this image. How did you do it?

Comment: I can't run it as well, does this answer still work? Or amazon modify something?

Comment: @CodaChang Are you using amazon linux or amazon Linux 2?

Comment: @AnujKumar I was trying to use RetHat7 image in AWS.

Comment: How to do it for Windows AMI

Answer (score 3):

Docker can create an image from a tar file using the `docker import` command.  From [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/):

```
Usage: docker import URL|- [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]

Create an empty filesystem image and import the contents of the tarball 
(.tar, .tar.gz, .tgz, .bzip, .tar.xz, .txz) into it, then optionally
tag it.
```

So you should be able to create a tar archive from your AMI image and then feed that to docker.

Comment: 'So you should be able to create a tar archive from your AMI image and then feed that to docker.' - how do I do that, I don't see an option in AWS to convert your AMI to tar ball.

Comment: You could boot an instance from that particular AMI and then run `tar` inside the instance, for example.

Comment: What does run tar inside the instance mean ? I would still need to throw something at tar.

Comment: @Scooby I would mount the target EBS volumen you want to dockerify as a non-boot volume on another instance. Then a syntax like `tar -czvf drive-image.tgz /media/my-external-drive`, assuming you mounted the volume at `/media/my-external-drive` and you have enough disk space on the root volume to hold the tar file.

Answer (score 1):

When creating the tar file `cd` to the directory and `tar` the tree from there.

```
cd /media/my-external-drive
tar -czvf /tmp/drive-image.tgz
```

And then to create the image ...

`docker import /tmp/drive-image.tgz`

This allows the `dockerized` container to create the correct paths when you run it.