# Import AMI image as Docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, tar, amazon-ami, rhel7

I have an AMI image created as a tar ball. The tar ball needs to be created as a Docker image. Steps followed are:

1) Create tar ball from AMI:
$sudo tar --numeric-owner --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys -cvf my-image.tar /images

2) Create Docker image from Tar ball:
$cat my-image.tar | sudo docker import - my-image:new

3) Run Docker image
$sudo docker run -it --rm --name my-image my-app-servers

Step #2 (Create Docker Image from Tar) is not working. It freezes. Nothing happens once Step#2 is issued. There are no error messages as well. Is there an other way to perform this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a docker image/container from EC2 AMI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324133/create-a-docker-image-container-from-ec2-ami)