# EC2 AMI to docker image

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I am running image-analysis software on an EC2 instance (ubuntu 14.04). Now, I am getting access to a university cluster (redhat linux v 6.5) with better (and cheaper) specifications. I am not allowed root-services for installation and they recommend using Docker. Now, the problem: I have no experience using docker whatsoever.

Is it possible to create an image of my EC2 instance and export/convert it to Docker for use on the university cluster?. If so - is there a tutorial for this somewhere (I haven't found any so far). Is it possible to save the image to Dropbox as an intermediary?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, but a related question with some options for how to proceed [Create a docker image/container from EC2 AMI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324133/create-a-docker-image-container-from-ec2-ami).

Comment: I did locate (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html). Although it doesnt dockerize the entire AMI I guess I can get the files I need into a docker.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Dockerize the entire AMI", could you explain that more?

Comment: @R0MANARMY - One way could be to create a docker image just with the application you need, but if there are a lot of applications, the cheapest way (in terms of time) would be to dockerize the entire AMI.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to pack your software inside another redhat linux image, where you have access to root. You can do something like this in your docker-file:

- Make a .Dockerfile where you configure your system as you want
- Copy all your project to the docker image that you started
- Run your software at the same port as before, if necessary, mapping it correctly.

You can take a look on this tutorial: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-build-a-docker-compose-file/

Comment: That's not what OP asked for.